# SQL injection and web log files

Tags: security

I need to kow how a SQL injection is recorded in log file. In other words I need an example of a web log file entry that contains a SQL injection. Another question please: the log file is recorded first or the query is executed at the database first?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your logs ; Search for single quote`(')` or `%27`. This is just a basic SQL Injection attack check when an attacker checks if your server is vulnerable.

In depth, you could also search for `' or 1=1--` (or) at the end of your querystring you will find this appended to it (`and 1=0--` or `and 1=1--`). This is a Blind SQL Injection attack test.

Comment: Thnaks but plz would u provide me an example? or guide me to article or forum that can give me information about example of sql injection in log file

Comment: No need for an example.. Just search for that highlighted keywords using a Find dialog on your log file.